# Как обойти ограничения VK API?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Всем нам известно, что например при поиске людей используя API вконтакт возвращает только первую 1000 результатов. Можно ли как-то обойти это ограничение?

Т.е. например если я буду искать людей чисто из Москвы, то будет написано что найдено 1..N человек, но вк отобразит только первую тысячу, как получить остальных?

Comment: Судя по документации этого сделать нельзя..

Comment: Если результаты каждый раз разные то можно делать повторные запросы.

Comment: Думаю, ограничение неспроста. Например, для того, чтобы кто-нибудь не заставил базу сдампить все таблицы. Почему бы не отнестись с пониманием к ограничениям?

Comment: Именно ограничения ВКонтакта обходить не стоит – приложение, уличённое в этом, рано или поздно забанят. Ваш вопрос, к счастью, не про нарушение, а про постраничную разбивку результатов поиска. Может, переформулируете заголовок на менее провокационный?

Comment: @bestdark, так ведь выдача ограниченного количества результатов вроде не зависит от количества обращений к API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Одним запросом нельзя - нужно выполнять несколько запросов, получая необходимую информацию постранично, относительно небольшими "порциями". При этом нужно соблюдать ограничения по количеству запросов на еденицу времени.

У большинства методов для этого есть параметр указывающий сдвиг - `offset`, в том числе и у используемого для поиска людей `users.search`.

В своём коде вам необходимо организовать простой цикл в котором вы будете выполнять запросы к API, постоянно увеличивая параметр `offset`(сдвиг) на указанный вами `count`(количество результатов), до тех пор, пока количество полученных результатов равно `count`(если меньше - вы получили последнуюю страницу результатов) либо до достижения другого необходимого вам условия.

Так же в цикле нужно организовать подсчет количества запросов, и вставлять временные паузы при достижении указанных в документации ограничений на количество вызовов метода.

Comment: Можно ускорить дело в 25 раз, используя метод [`execute()`](https://vk.com/dev/execute): внутри него к API можно обратиться до 25 раз.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того чтобы четко соблюдать ограничения между запросами можно использовать несколько акаунтов для распределения запросов и увлечения скорости.
А так же пользоваться прокси/впн/ssh серверами.